# list style image not showing icon

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css and I am trying to list items with an image called pie_bullet.png. There are many nested lists and I am not able to make it work. can anyone help me please?
The items I want to list with the image using css are the list items "li" in both classes

```html
<ul type="a">
  <li>preheat Oven: preheat oven to 350 degrees F(175 degrees C).</li>
  <li>Make Lemon Filling: In a medium saucepan ...</li>
  <ul class="first">
    <li>Whisk together 1 cup sugar, flour, cornstarch, and salt.</li>
    <li>Stir in water, lemon juice and lemon zest.</li>
    <li>Cook over medium-high heat, stirring frequently, until mixture comes to a boil.</li>
    <li>Stir in butter.</li>
    <li>Place egg yolks in a small bowl and gradually whisk in 1/2 cup of hot sugar mixture.</li>
    <li>Whisk egg yolk mixture back into remaining sugar mixture.</li>
    <li>Bring to a boil and continue to cook while stirring constantly until thick.</li>
    <li>Remove from heat.</li>
    <li>Pour filling into baked pastry shell.</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Make Meringue: In a large glass or metal bowl ...</li>
  <ul class="second">
    <li>Whip egg whites until foamy.</li>
    <li>Add sugar gradually, and continue to whip until stiff peaks form.</li>
    <li>Spread meringue over pie, sealing the edges at the crust.</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Bake: Bake in preheated oven for 10 minutes, or until meringue is golden brown</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should post your HTML code examples along with your post. You wouldn't expect people to go through an external link

Comment: I just added a snippet, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ul class add this method to li class

```css
li {
    list-style:none;
    background-image: url("http://www.icone-png.com/png/7/7359.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left center;
 background-size: 40px;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul type="a">
  <li>preheat Oven: preheat oven to 350 degrees F(175 degrees C).</li>
  <li>Make Lemon Filling: In a medium saucepan ...</li>
  <ul class="first">
    <li>Whisk together 1 cup sugar, flour, cornstarch, and salt.</li>
    <li>Stir in water, lemon juice and lemon zest.</li>
    <li>Cook over medium-high heat, stirring frequently, until mixture comes to a boil.</li>
    <li>Stir in butter.</li>
    <li>Place egg yolks in a small bowl and gradually whisk in 1/2 cup of hot sugar mixture.</li>
    <li>Whisk egg yolk mixture back into remaining sugar mixture.</li>
    <li>Bring to a boil and continue to cook while stirring constantly until thick.</li>
    <li>Remove from heat.</li>
    <li>Pour filling into baked pastry shell.</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Make Meringue: In a large glass or metal bowl ...</li>
  <ul class="second">
    <li>Whip egg whites until foamy.</li>
    <li>Add sugar gradually, and continue to whip until stiff peaks form.</li>
    <li>Spread meringue over pie, sealing the edges at the crust.</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Bake: Bake in preheated oven for 10 minutes, or until meringue is golden brown</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an image to a list:

```
<ul>
 <li><img src="path to file.png" alt="quick description"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is super helpful if you post your code as text.  That way we can see all of it, and help edit.

Try the following CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
```

Hope this helps!

edit:  Based on the code you posted, the following CSS works:

```
.first li {
list-style-image: url("icon.png");
```

Comment: I posted the code as you told me, thank you for your advice! I tried what you did but I am doing it wrong .. it is not working